# Calling Method In View in Razor Web Pages

Tags: .net, asp.net, razor

I have a custom view base class that inherits from WebPage.  I want in Razor to call a method in this class, but I keep getting errors saying "the method 'X' does not exist in the current context."  Since I'm essentially using the method like any of the other methods (RenderPage, for example), why is this not working?  What am I missing here?

I do have my view registered because I am using other methods of it in the `@functions` block...

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Nucleo.Web.Views.BaseViewWebPage" />
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Are you getting this error in the VS designer or at runtime?

Comment: Views aren't compiled.  If you hit F5, what happens?

Comment: Build Started > Build Failed "Error 1 The name 'RenderViewPage' does not exist in the current context C:\..\Parent.cshtml 20 7 C:\...\
"

Comment: Are you using the MSBuild target for CSHTML files?

Comment: @Slaks It's an ordinary ASP.NET Razor web site with no special build, other than to specify my custom page base type as above.  Everything works well with my implementation; it builds fine, and I can call any of my base view methods in the functions { } block of the Razor web page (other methods called there fine), but not inside the view as a RenderViewPage call...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4055/discussion-between-brian-and-slaks)

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WebPages? They both use Razor, but there are differences. Also, please include the exact line of code that causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but the DLL never refreshed, and that is why I was getting the error.  When I deleted it and rebuilt, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like you are trying to call RenderViewPage(), but there is no such method on WebPage. I assume you want to call RenderPage() instead, which should work.